# Is there a more precise version of WinUser.h's SetCursorPos() function for mouse movement in C++ (for a Windows console application)?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm making a program that translates Xbox controller joystick inputs into mouse movements on the Windows 10 desktop using Xinput. After googling for a bit, I found the SetCursorPos() function, which is a part of the standard Windows.h library (specifically the WinUser.h dependency).

However, SetCursorPos() only takes integer inputs for the coordinates, and only recognizes my 3840x2160 (4K) laptop screen as 1536x864. Is there a more precise version of SetCursorPos that can take double or float type inputs, or has a higher 'resolution'? Is there a way to increase the resolution of SetCursorPos()?

Comment: Most likely, you need to mark your application as [high DPI aware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process). Then the OS wouldn't lie to it about the monitor's dimensions.

Comment: Or you could set the Zoom level for your laptop display to 100% (rather than 250%), but then you'd probably have a hard time reading text that small.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I don't know anything about XML, but I'll try it out doing it through a manifest file.